# How to insert or delete to ModelList in RoomDatabase at runtime?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have a room database and saving my all entity. After that I call a service and saving all of this table.(Entity table work like cache. İt load my list before service call). But sometimes added new column from service side and everything is OK now. But sometimes a column deleted. How can I handle this case.

> @Activity

```
fillList(roomDao.getAll())
restApi.getEntityList()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(
    { r ->
        val entityList: List<Entity> = r.multiData
        roomDao.insertAll(entityList)

        fillList(entityList)
    }
```

> @Dao

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insertAll(List<Entity> room);
```

Is there any Room method like `InsertOrDelete()`
Thanks for any help.

Comment: you have Delete and Insert annotation in your DAO class.
you can add and delete objects using these annotations.

Comment: I dont want to clear all list and add again. I want to compare and delete only changed item like an annotion or something like this.

Comment: then try adding unique key to each object and check if that object is present in that list if yes check if its equal or changed . if changed then replace that object or update.

Comment: Isn't that possible with Room annotation? I dont want to write nested foreach loop

Comment: dnt use foreach loop check onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE will replace if there is same object or changes in it